# how to change my value in this read method firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to read my data in database, so i use firebase, when i want read my data, i use this code

```
DatabaseReference nortjo87Ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tes");

    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.w("", "value is: "+ value);
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w("", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // ...
        }
    };

    nortjo87Ref.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

and i see in the run bar, i see my value is already changed, but after this, when i set my text view with "value(String)",

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.w("", "value is: "+ value);
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w("", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // ...
        }
    };

    nortjo87Ref.addValueEventListener(postListener);

    tvText.setText(value);
```

the value is null, so i wanna ask, **how to pick my value of this (My text View)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code `tvText.setText(value);` inside `onDataChange`:

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.w("", "value is: "+ value);
            tvText.setText(value);
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w("", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // ...
        }
    };
```

That's because `onDataChange` is asynchronous which means the code after it will be executed before it retrieves the full data, therefore you got null on the textView